# How to disable attributes breaking in element tags with Prettier

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, eslint, prettier, prettier-eslint

I generated a new Vue project using Vue CLI. For the linter option prompt, I chose Prettier. How do I disable the breaking of attributes to new lines? For instance:

This is my markup:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer
  v-model="drawer"
  :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
  app
>
   ...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

and my expected output is this:

```html
<v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp" app>
   ...
</v-navigation-drawer>
```

I tried to create `.prettierrc` file, and added this configuration:

```js
{
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

but that didn't work for me, and the HTML still looks the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Prettier option being enforced here is [`printWidth`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width), which has a default of 80. The markup line in question is 82 characters long plus the length of the preceding tab space, which causes the linter/formatter to break up the line.

You could increase the `printWidth` to address the issue:

```js
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    //...
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "warn",
      {
        printWidth: 180,  // default = 80
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for Angular and for HTML:

`<!-- prettier-ignore-attribute *ngFor -->` will exclude the *ngFor (angular attribute) from being formatted.

This works for all kinds of attributes in HTML files.

I don't really know how to make that work for Vue, but I hope you guys can figure it out. There was no documentation for angular either, but it worked out of the box.
Although, for the case you are asking for, you could probably just ignore the next line, if that is possible somehow. Otherwise use a block-ignore statement and disable it after the next line.

Documentation: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html#html